# Bootstrap Links in Modal not working: JQuery error

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="product-add-to-cart-modal-ssbt" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                        <div class="row quick-view product-main">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">

                                <p class="lead text-center">One <b>{Product Name}</b> will be added to your cart.
                                </p>  

                                <div class="box">
                                    <p class="text-muted text-small text-center">
                                        What do you want to do next?
                                    </p>

                                    <div class="box-footer" id="add-to-cart-buttons">
                                        <a href="?add_product=10161">
                                            <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>Return to current page
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="/site/cart?add_product=10161">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Go to shopping cart
                                        </a>
                                    </div>    
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.box -->

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/.modal-dialog-->
        </div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-add-to-cart-modal-ssbt" onclick="return false;">Add to cart</button>
```

When I click any of the two links in my modal, it doesn't go anywhere.  Looking at the Console, I see this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ?add_product=10161

Then it references **jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2** on the right.

I cannot replicate my error in JSFiddle.  It works there.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gk6o4cmr/

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try assigning a fully qualified URL - *http://....?add_product=10161*

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://...?add_product=10161

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/suun90a2/. I have modified `<a>` little and used jQuery. For some reason Modal does not work for Query parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the href tag to data-href.  I'm working within a framework and I can only change the href attribute and the text inside the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
This button and modal is inside a tab.  And for some reason I had a piece of script at the bottom of this page that was changing the behaviour of achor tags inside the tab div.

```
jQuery('#product_details_tabs a').not('.external-link').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  jQuery(this).tab('show')
})
```

It turns out that after I had updated some of my code, I didn't need this script anyway, so by just deleting it, the problem went away.